# what is the correct way to write this mysql query?? "SELECT SUM(buyingPrice-(buyingPrice*10/100))"

Tags: mysql, sql

what is the correct way to write this mysql query?? "SELECT SUM(buyingPrice-(buyingPrice*10/100))"
I wanna get the calculation done by the query?? Is this even possible??

Comment: as far as I understand you, you calculate 90% of an sum? so I would write SELECT SUM(buyingPrice)*0.9 from ... But still, your question is unclear.

Comment: Your query looks OK. What is the input and expected result?

Comment: Please update your question properly, not clear, the aggregate function Sum() you wrote it seems like ok, but why you are questioning about it, please explain.

Comment: no I want to calculate the depreciation of a machine in a simple way. So my machine table have these coulumns(mchnID,mchnName,buyingPrice,buyingDate,useFulLifeTime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html I suspect you need to group by mchnid. for example

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(mchnID int,mchnName varchar(3),buyingPrice int,buyingDate date,useFulLifeTime int);

insert into t value
(1,'aaa',100,'2019-01-01',10),
(2,'bbb',1000,'2019-01-01',10); 

SELECT mchnid,SUM(buyingPrice-(buyingPrice*10/100)) depr
from t
group by mchnid

+--------+----------+
| mchnid | depr     |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |  90.0000 |
|      2 | 900.0000 |
+--------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```